# Hide the "Mass Delete " field in Accounts

Tags: account

How do I hide or disable the Mass Delete field in accounts using the Professional Edition as in Professional Edition there is no Profiles?

Comment: Buy "custom profiles", or live with the fact that users can do this. I don't know of any other way to do this.